# What whould be the MySql relationship

Tags: mysql, mongodb

Lets consider one case, we have services at three levels

```
Rose
       -red rose
                 - red rose by A dealer
                 - red rose by B dealer
       -yellow rose
                 - yellow rose by A dealer
                 - yellow rose by B dealer
```

So what would be the ideal scenario for creating database relations between tables:

I want to create db structure for product and service/flavours. for example lets say rose is my product then red rose, yellow rose, black rose are my services and further red rose by A dealer and red rose by B dealer is further my services...in this scenario how I will make collections in mongodb.

Comment: You've tagged this question both as mysql and as mongodb. These two databases differ greatly in how they handle relations. A schema which works well in one might not work so well in the other.

Comment: Yeah but you can answer considering any of them I will interpret it.

Comment: your question is if you're doing correct implementation, but I don't see any implementation at all. What are the products and services and how do they relate to each other? What are the fields in those tables? Also remember that MongoDB is a document based database and not a relational database, that's a **very** important thing to understand before you jump into NoSQL.

Comment: With respect @rednaw I want to create db structure for product and service/flavours. for example lets say Apartment is my product then 2 BHK, 3 BHK are my services and further 2 bhk by this Developer and 2 BHk by that Developer is further my services...in this scenario how I will make collections in mongodb.

Comment: I have no idea what a BHK is. Maybe you should rethink your question to make it clearer for outsiders. You can also edit your question, then post a comment that your question is updated.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you want to know. And I don't know what a BHK is. Could you edit your question so we can understand it? Do you already have a solution (for mongodb or mysql) and want to port the solution to other technology?

Comment: @rednaw I have edited my question...pls let me know if my I had make my point clear or not..thanks

Comment: @hgoebl question edited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data seems relational. MongoDB is not a relational database. That means you can't create relations in your data. If you want to use MongoDB you'll have to create the relations between the data yourself. If it's worth it, that's up to you. Most people choose MongoDB for speed, but when your data is very dependent on relationships, MongoDB might not help you at all.

So if you would create this strucuture in MongoDB, you would have three different collections: `roses`, `flavors` and `dealers`. If you want to get a rose for a certain flavor and a certain dealer, you'll have to execute 3 separate queries, and then join the 3 results together, where in mysql you can do 1 query where you get 1 result. Note that this difference gets bigger with every layer of relationships.

It could still be possible that doing the separate MongoDB queries is faster in the end, if your collections are really large, and maybe if you need to do complex filtering on it. You should just remember that it's not a free lunch, you'll have a completely different setup compared to a relational database and you should really think about it.

For speed, you can also consider adding a cache layer on top of your relational database, which you could in fact use MongoDB for.

Comment: I got downvoted for this, could somebody explain why?

Comment: One thing I can think of is that your speed estimation based on queries and results is not entirely accurate, that is a SQL-ie way of thinking of things. In reality the 3 queries can be just as fast as the one and have less over head due to not needing to create a result set or pipe the results out via IO etc etc.

Comment: @Sammaye well said....but I think rednaw has explained 3 queries and 1 query to make his point...But in reality the scope of my data is known to me only.... Basically you are going towards optimization and we are talking about implementation...Sorry this what I understand

Comment: @Sammaye I updated my answer to point out that Mongo can still be faster.

Comment: Though do remember I was not the one who downvoted, I just tried to think of why others might have downvoted